# How to prevent Jenkins SCM polling from triggering a build on branch creation

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have git SCM polling set up in my Jenkins server job. I run the following commands on my local machine and they trigger a Jenkins build:

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
git branch feature/new-feature
git checkout feature/new-feature
git push origin dev:feature/new-feature
```

Is there any way to prevent Jenkins SCM polling from triggering a build when the only thing that changed was branch creation (no new commits)?

Comment: What type of job are you using? Is it a a regular pipeline, or multibranch pipeline, etc.?

Comment: My job is a regular pipeline. My work-around for now is to not push my new branch until it has the commits I want built.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the "Skip initial build on first branch indexing" option in your Jenkins project. For Multibranch project this option can be found behind the "Build strategies" section.